# jquery sortable lists with dynamically generated list ids

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

For my webpage, I have a number of lists which I'm generating dynamically from the database. Each list is generated like so:

```
<ul id = "<%= "subgroups_for_tumourgroup_" + item.ID %>">
```

I'm trying to make them sortable using jquery's sortable list

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

    $('#subgroups_for_tumourgroup_1').sortable();

    });   
</script>
```

The question is, given that I may have any number of IDs (the "1" in the code above is the ID) and they may not even be sequential (I may have lists called "subgroups_for_tumourgroup_1", and "subgroups_for_tumourgroup_3", but no "subgroups_for_tumourgroup_2", how do I make all those lists independantly sortable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)  to match all IDs up to the point right before the number that gives them their uniqueness:

```
// make all ULs whose id starts with 'subgroups_for_tumourgroup_' into sortables
$('ul[id^=subgroups_for_tumourgroup_]').sortable();
```

That said, can't you just use a class selector instead, and not have to bother with IDs?

```
$("ul.sortable").sortable();
```

Comment: Oh wow, that works - I had no idea I could make a .sortable call on a text match pattern rather than the exact name, and I was trying to parse out the ID from the <ul> tag and do string concatenation and looping through all of them. Thanks a bunch.